# Sorting Array issue in iOS app

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting

I have an array like:

> (
>       "8461.86","8468.22","8468.22","8162.59","8164.50","7280.59" )

I try to sort this array decendingly as per following:

```
sortedArray = [arr_distance sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

But i got following array like:

> (
>       "7280.59","8162.59","8164.50","8461.86","8468.22","8468.22" )

Why this happen?

I also try with like

```
return [firstObject compare:secondObject options:NSNumericSearch];
```

But not getting proper sorted array.

Comment: Where's the question about Xcode?

Comment: The sort you provided is sorting in ascending order. This is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"" ascending:NO];
NSMutableArray *yourTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"8459.93",@"8466.28",@"8466.28",@"8160.70",@"8162.61",@"7278.56", nil];
[yourTempArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
NSLog(@"sotedAr == %@",yourTempArray);
```

**Output:**

```
sotedAr == (
"8466.28",
"8466.28",
"8459.93",
"8162.61",
"8160.70",
"7278.56"
```

)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But my values can be repeated i.e. same value can repeated more than once.

Comment: So what ? It gives you in the sorted list rite? For Ex: 5,6,7,8,5 then output comes as 8,7,6,5,5 rite ?

Comment: thanks for your reply! But when i give array like: NSMutableArray *yourTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"8459.93",@"8466.28",@"8466.28",@"8160.70",@"8162.61",@"7278.56", nil];  **It is not properly sorted**

Comment: dude don't copy and paste your objects. See the output and i got the output as above

Comment: sorry i made some mistake that's why i didn't get proper array

Answer (score 2):

To sort in **descending** order, you could just switch the firstObject and secondObject in your code:

```
sortedArray = [arr_distance sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
  return [((NSString *)secondObject) compare:((NSString *)firstObject) options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code may be useful for sorting your array in descending order

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8459.93",@"8466.28",@"8466.28",@"8160.70",@"8162.61",@"7278.56", nil];
NSMutableArray *yourTempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[yourTempArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
NSLog(@"before sorting = %@",yourTempArray);
NSSortDescriptor* sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];

[yourTempArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
NSLog(@"After sorting = %@",yourTempArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But i am not getting the sorted array.

Comment: @user2243212,Did u tried that code, it will surely sort the arrray in descending order

Comment: @user2243212, just copy and paste the above code in your project's viewdidload function , run the project and see the output

Comment: sorry, you are right. Due my mistake i didn't get proper array. I like to give up vote but due to low Reputation, I can't do it. Sorry once again..

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:-

```
NSSortDescriptor *frequencyDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@""
                                                               ascending:NO
                                                              comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                                                  return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
                                                              }];
NSEnumerator * enumerator = [arr_distance objectEnumerator];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frequencyDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray =   [arr_distance sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
enumerator = [sortedArray objectEnumerator];
NSLog(@"sortedArray = %@",sortedArray);
```

// use sortedArray which is sorted

Comment: Thanks for Your Reply! But not get properly sorted array. I have distance array like:("8459.93","8466.28","8466.28","8160.70","8162.61","7‌​278.56")

Comment: sorry, you are right. Due my mistake i didn't get proper array. I like to give up vote but due to low Reputation, I can't do it. Sorry once again...